# NPM installation issue: Unknown system error -75

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

I've searched around on the internet high and low and I haven't been able to find a solution for the following error:

`Error: Unknown system error -75: Unknown system error -75, scandir '/var/www/project/sites/admin'
(node:11725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

This occurs when I attempt to do run anything with npm. The error below as created when running `npm install`.
I tried removing npm and node completely, then reinstalling, but I still get the same error.

Node version: v8.12.0

Vagrant: 2.02

Vbox: 5.2.18

Linux 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:32 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Update: i'm currently installing nvm to see if i can get it to work with a different version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated this issue using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Turns out this was an [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23677) with node v8.12. Switching to any other node version fixes this issue. I hope this helps someone else!